# children radio button validation with jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I have 2radio buttons . One radio button has 3sub level  radio button.
Ex:

```
    <input type="radio"  name="catagory" />
                  <label class="" for="">A</label>
  <input type="radio" class="btn-redio" name="catagory" />
                  <label class="" for="">B</label>
```

once i cheked the radio button B i will get 3sub level of radio buttons.
I want to validate that if a user clicks B then need to check whether any sub radio butto is checked or not   .

sub level means:if click the button B then only another 3radio buttons will be displayed by JS

Thanks

AZ

Comment: What do you mean by _3sub level radio button_? You haven't tried anything, at least post all the related markup.

Comment: once clicked the button B then 3 sub radio buttons will be appended by JS like

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this is your situation:

```
<input type="radio" name="parent_radio1" value="..." />
<input type="radio" name="sub_radio1_1" value="..." />
<input type="radio" name="sub_radio1_2" value="..." />
<input type="radio" name="sub_radio1_3" value="..." />

<input type="radio" name="parent_radio2" value="..." />
<input type="radio" name="sub_radio2_1" value="..." />
<input type="radio" name="sub_radio2_2" value="..." />
<input type="radio" name="sub_radio2_3" value="..." />
```

If that is the case you could use something like this (not tested):

```
var form = $('#someForm');
form.submit(function(event){
  var parent_radios = $('input[type=radio][name^="parent_radio"]');
  parent_radios.each(function(){
    var parent = $(this);

    if (parent.prop('checked') !== true) return; // Parent not selected, no validation needed

    var child_selector = parent.attr('name').replace('parent_radio', '');
    var childs = $('input[name^="sub_radio' + child_selector + '_"]:checked'); // Select only the selected ones

    if (childs.length == 0) {
      event.preventDefault(); // No sub radio has been selected for this parent, cancel submit
      // Do some other stuff here like show error message
    }
  });

});
```